# Attribute table in QGIS won't save custom values

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing, qgis-2

I am trying to edit a point shapefile in QGIS and I have editing on for that layer. I have added a new column for the custom data, I have set it to text and have 8 characters allowed in the column, but every time I save and toggle editing off all of the values go back to null.

Comment: This may or may not help, but sometimes simply closing and reopening the attribute table has resolved this for me in the past.  Stupid workaround but nonetheless it has worked.  Also, do you have any Joins on the layer while editing? This has also caused similar behavior when editing for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There may be something weird with the shapefile, in case `QGIS` *have write access* on this file.

In this case, I have two ideas for you:

**1)** To diagnosticate the shapefile for anomalies, using the **[shp_doctor](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/index)** tool.

If you are on *Windows* and you don't want to loose time with the **[shp_doctor](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/index)** compilation from sources, then you may 
 download a working executable, *tested for viruses*, from [here](http://www.findthatzip-file.com/search-97928550-fZIP/winrar-winzip-download-shp_doctor-4.0.0-win-x86.zip.htm). (Press the yellow button - *Download now, File Size: 567.1 kb*)

Below is such a test, with a healthy file, but I'm expecting in your case, to see a hint for your shapefile bad behaviour:

[image]

**2)** I think this is the *quick-and-dirty* way to solve your problem, regardless of the cause of errors (*I hope not to be wrong!*):

- open up the attribute table of your *weird* shapefile;
- select only those *healthy* point features, omitting those with `null` values;
- right click the layer name and choose `Save Selection As...`;
- choose `ESRI Shapefile` as *Format*;
- choose a `name` and a `location` for the new, *healty* layer;
- check `Add saved file to map` and press *Ok*.

Now, working with the new point layer should be smooth!